# Probability of death of one of three children with given mortality?

Tags: probability

Background: In the United States, in 1920, the **mortality rate for children under age of $5$** per $1,000$ births was $180$. ([United States all time child mortality rate](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1041693/united-states-all-time-child-mortality-rate/)).

1. What is the probability of death of (at least) one of three children with given mortality?
2. What is the probability of death of all three children with given mortality?

With this probability, the chance that one out of three children will die is $45$%*, and that all three will die is $0.6$%**.

So I calculate it as independent events:

ad. *
This one is $1 - P(A′)^3$ ;where $P(A′) = 1 − P(A)$ (opposite event)

$$P_1 = 1 - P(A′)^3 = 1-(1-0.18)^3 = 0.4486$$

ad. **
$$P_3 = P(A)^3 = (0.18)^3 = 0.0058$$

Am I right with that?

How would it change if I wanted to calculate probability for exactly one child (or two for that matter)?

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but we will all die with probabliity $1$. Have you missed something out of your statements numbered 1 and 2?

Comment: Your calculations are OK **if** we assume *independence* among the children. That may or may not be a valid assumption.

Comment: $P_1$ as you calculated is for at least one dying, not only one dying.

Comment: To elaborate on herb's comment, the first part of the problem is phrased ambiguously. It's not clear whether it means *exactly* one of three or *at least* one of three. (I overlooked this point in my previous comment.)

Comment: How do I approve edit suggest?

Comment: We don't all die as children, certainly not under age of 5.

Comment: I assume it's independent. It's more that less is as children are not born in same time and are different.

Comment: @herb-steinberg: that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct.

For exactly one child, the event looks like

$$
(A\cap A'\cap A')\cup(A'\cap A\cap A')\cup(A'\cap A'\cap A) \Rightarrow
$$

$$
\text{Pr}\left[(A\cap A'\cap A')\cup(A'\cap A\cap A')\cup(A'\cap A'\cap A)\right] =  3\cdot \text{Pr}(A)\cdot \left(\text{Pr}(A')\right)^2 = 3\cdot 0.18 \cdot \left(1-0.18\right)^2
$$

***Adding another approach from my comment below***.

The problem can be solved by using Binomial distribution: say you have an event $A$, and $\text{Pr}()=p$, $\text{Pr}(A')=1−p$. You repeat an experiment $n$ times,and you are interested in the probability that $A$ occurs $m$ times out of $n$ repetitions of the experiment. Obviously, that $0\leq m \leq n$.

Then,

$$
\text{Pr}(m) = {n\choose m}p^m(1-p)^{n-m}.
$$

In our case, $n = 3$, $p = 0.18 \Rightarrow $

$$
\text{Pr}(m=1) = {3 \choose 1}\cdot 0.18\cdot (1−0.18)^2 = 3\cdot 0.18\cdot (1−0.18)^2.
$$

$$
\text{Pr}(m=2) = {3 \choose 2}\cdot 0.18\cdot (1−0.18)^2 = 3\cdot 0.18^2\cdot (1−0.18).
$$

Probability that $A$ occurs at least 1 time is equal to

$$
\text{Pr}(m\geq 1) = 1 - \text{Pr}(m = 0) = 1 - {3 \choose 0}\cdot 0.18^0\cdot (1−0.18)^3 = 1 - (1-0.18)^3.
$$

Comment: Does it mean for two would be P[(A ∩ A ∩ A') ∪ (A ∩ A' ∩ A) ∪ (A' ∩ A ∩ A)] =  3·P(A)^2·(1-P(A))?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Another approach to solving this problem is using Binomial distribution: say you have an event $A$, and $\text{Pr}(A) = p$, $\text{Pr}(A') = 1-p$. You repeat an experiment $n$ times, and you are interested in the probability that $A$ occurs $m$ times out of $n$ repetitions of the experiment. Obviously, that $0 \leq m \leq n$. $\text{Pr}(m) = {n \choose m} p^m(1-p)^{n-m}$. In our case, $n = 3$, $p = 0.18$ => $\text{Pr}(m =1) =  {3 \choose 1} 0.18 (1-0.18)^2 = 3\cdot 0.18\cdot (1-0.18)^2$. Or $\text{Pr}(m =2) =  {3 \choose 2} 0.18^2 (1-0.18) = 3\cdot 0.18^2\cdot (1-0.18)$.

Comment: Put it in your answer, that would be complete.